# Can I define Spring Cloud Contract to act as proxy, and only make stubs for subset of endpoints?

Tags: wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

With Wiremock you can define a proxy so that if none of defined stub mappings match for a given request, Wiremock forwards that request to a given host:port. Is that behaviour available with Spring Cloud Contract DSL ?

I could not find anything of that feature in SCC documentation (with my browser find command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach is not present via the dsl. You can create wiremock proxies and package them to a stub jar yourself. Then stub runner could pick those and start such a proxy.